# Anything similar to a microcontroller interrupt handler?

Tags: python

Is there some method where one could use a try statement to catch an error caused by a raise statement, execute code to handle the flag e.g. update some variables and then return to the line where the code had been operating when the flag was raised?

I am thinking specifically of an interrupt handler for a micro-controller (which does what ive just described).

I am writing some code that has a thread checking a file to see if it updates and I want it to interrupt the main program so it is aware of the update, deals with it appropriately, and returns to the line it was running when interrupted.

Ideally, the main program would recognize the flag from the thread regardless of where it is in execution. A try statement would do this but how could I return to the line where the flag was raised?

Thanks!
Paul

EDIT:

My attempt at ISR after comments albeit it looks like a pretty straight forward example of using locks. Small test routine at the bottom to demonstrate code

```
    import os
    import threading
    import time

    def isr(path, interrupt):
        prev_mod = os.stat(path).st_mtime
        while(1):  
            new_mod = os.stat(path).st_mtime
            if new_mod != prev_mod:
                print "Updates! Waiting to begin"
                # Prevent enter into critical code and updating
                # While the critical code is running.
                with interrupt:     
                    print "Starting updates"
                    prev_mod = new_mod
                    print "Fished updating"
            else:
                print "No updates"
                time.sleep(1)

    def func2(interrupt): 
        while(1):
            with interrupt:     # Prevent updates while running critical code
                # Execute critical code
                print "Running Crit Code"
                time.sleep(5)
                print "Finished Crit Code"
            # Do other things

    interrupt = threading.Lock()

    path = "testfil.txt"
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = isr, args = (path, interrupt))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = func2, args = (interrupt,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    # Create and "Update" to the file
    time.sleep(12)
    chngfile = open("testfil.txt","w")
    chngfile.write("changing the file")
    chngfile.close()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: What's the significance of having the main thread deal with it, as opposed to having some other, possibly dedicated, thread do it?

Comment: I didn't discount doing it in another thread, I just phrased the question from the point of view I was thinking from, that of coding microcontrollers. My example code does exactly what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One standard OS way to handle interrupts is to enqueue the interrupt so another kernel thread can process it.

This partially applies in Python.

> I am writing some code that has a thread checking a file to see if it updates and I want it to interrupt the main program so it is aware of the update, deals with it appropriately, and returns to the line it was running when interrupted.

You have multiple threads.  You don't need to "interrupt" the main program.  Simply "deal with it appropriately" in a separate thread.  The main thread will find the updates when the other thread has "dealt with it appropriately".

This is why we have locks.  To be sure that shared state is updated correctly.

You interrupt a thread by locking a resource the thread needs.

You make a thread interruptable by acquiring locks on resources.

Comment: Its not quite in the same spirit as an ISR as it is preventing lines executing while waiting for a lock rather than interrupting at any point and returning to that line when finished. I made a pretty basic piece of code that does what I want with your advice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Paul: Be careful of how you describe hardware/OS interrupts.  While a hardware interrupt may -- in principle -- be resumable, no OS actually allows that resumption without checking with the scheduler and determining which thread is highest priority.

Answer (score 1):

In python we call that pattern "function calls".  You cannot do this with exceptions; exceptions only unroll the stack, and always to the first enclosing `except` clause.

Microcontrollers have interrupts to support asynchronous events; but the same mechanism is also used in software interrupts for system calls, because an interrupt can be configured to have a different set of protection bits; the system call can be allowed to do more than the user program calling it.  Python doesn't have any kind of protection levels like this, and so software interrupts are not of much use here.

As for handling asynchronous events, you can do that in python, using the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module, but you may want to step lightly if you are also using threads.